# Can't write floating point aiff file in Python

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, aiff

I'm an audio developer and would like to read and write 32 bit floating point audio files from python for test purposes. After hours of farting around, I've managed to realize that the problems I'm having are restricted to the floating point format. I can successfully write a 16 bit fixed point file from a numpy array (even though there are no examples in the aifc documentation).

I also saw a couple other libraries PySoundFile and Audiolab, though they were either really old and/or didn't install properly.

What is the right way to get this done in python? There are a shocking lack of google results on the subject of writing sound files in python.

The following code does not work, but is based on very similar code which *does* work for 16 bit fixed point data.

```
 def write_test_float_aiff(data):
   f = aifc.open('test.aiff', 'w')
   f.setframerate(44100)
   f.setnchannels(1)
   f.setsampwidth(4)
   f.writeframes(data)
   f.close()

r = np.arange(0,1000,.1)
s = np.sin(r)
write_test_float_aiff(s.byteswap().tostring())
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about "does not work"? What goes wrong? Do you get an exception? Do you get audio that sounds wrong in some way? If you get an exception, post it, including full stack trace.

Comment: I don't see anything here that would specify 32-bit floating-point data. Does AIFF even support that? It sounds like you need to make an AIFF-C file, and set the compression type.

Comment: Although, looking at the [`aifc` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/aifc.html#aifc.aifc.setcomptype), I don't think the module even supports raw 32-bit floating-point data.

Comment: The AIFF format does support 32 bit floats. It's hard to tell anything about the AIFC module since the documentation is so minimal. 

I just got this working using PySoundFile (which has been renamed to soundfile). I will write a more detailed assessment after some more investigation. BTW, "does not work" means nonsense data. AIFC doesn't seem to provide a way to specify floating point data, so that is probably part of the problem.